# How do I Uniquely identify an appx package

Tags: windows-store-apps, uwp

I'm working on a UWP app that will be installed on a device running Windows 10 IoT.

I need to be able to uniquely identify the appx package that corresponds to my app.  I need something that is not going to change between builds and releases.

I am able to the following information from a web request to `http://insertIPAddressHere:8080/api/app/packagemanager/packages:

Ive removed the bits the parts that might be sensitive, but you can type `Get-AppxPackage` into powershell to get an idea of what the removed fields look like.  The `PackageFamilyName` from powershell seems to correlate with the `PackageRelativeId` from the web request.

```
{
   "InstalledPackages":[
         ...
      {
         "CanUninstall":true,
         "Name":"removed",
         "PackageFamilyName":"removed",
         "PackageFullName":"removed",
         "PackageOrigin":5,
         "PackageRelativeId":"removed",
         "Publisher":"removed",
         "Version":{
            "Build":68,
            "Major":0,
            "Minor":0,
            "Revision":0
         },
         "RegisteredUsers":[
            {
               "UserDisplayName":"removed",
               "UserSID":"removed"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I thought about hardcoding in the `PackageRelativeId`, but I'm not sure if that's an appropriate way to identify my app.  It has what what looks like some randomly generated characters, and I haven't yet found anything that reassures me that value will remain the same between builds and revisions.  I can't find it anywhere in my solution.  It's only mentioned in some of the compiled files.

Answer (score 0):

`PackageFullName` is your unique identifier in this case -- it will encode the package name, version, and publisher.

If you ***don't*** want the package version as part of your identifier, use `PackageFamilyName`.

You can see all this via powershell:

```
get-appxpackage | where name -eq "My.PackageName"
```

Comment: The problem with `PackageFamilyName` is that I'm not sure where it's defined at in my solution.  Is there a chance that it will ever change without me knowing about it?